# Possible reasons of electrocution in a good earthed appliance during sudden power off

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits

I was working in a industry. When I was using a machine, I felt slight electrical shock at the exact moment when the power supply went off. The machine is properly earthed. In spite of that I got shock.

What could be the possible reasons of electrocution in a good earthed appliance during such sudden power off

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question about physics

Comment: Why did the power supply shut off? That may help determine the fault.

Comment: If you felt a shock the machine is _not_ properly wired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the AC motors will create a "back pressure" once power has been removed.  I do however not believe you when you say you have a properly grounded piece of equipment.  Please note...the grounding system must be complete ALL The way back to a earth ground (grounding rod ect)...grounding cables can have a tendency to create a thin film of oxidation on them causing them to "look" fine...but in reality have very poor continuity.  Attach a multimeter to a cold water ground and the framework of the equipment...turn it off....if it registers..you have a bad ground.

Comment: Using a regular multimeter as an ohmmeter will only tell if the grounding is really, really terrible. To spot most problems with grounding you need to apply a somewhat heavy load that goes via ground and calculate the resistance based on that. Or simply use a more advanced piece of equipment, like Metrel EuroTest. That is how electricians test earthing/grounding.